# Code Igniter Cannot Update Data (no error)

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem in updating data in codeigniter. There's no error message but The data cannot be updated when i change the data name and click submit the button.

I'm new in CI so i cant really figure out where did i do wrong. can you help me?

thankyou in advance

my view (views/form/form_edit_bank.php)

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('bankdatel/updatebank/'.$row_bank['idbank']);?>" method="post">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nama Bank: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="namabank" value="<?php echo $row_bank['namabank']?>">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ubah</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

controller (controllers/bankdatel.php)

```
public function editbank(){

        $this->load->model('model_bankdatel');
        $data['row_bank'] = $this->model_bankdatel->selectbank($this->uri->segment(2));

        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('form/form_edit_bank', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }


    public function updatebank(){

        $arrdata = array(
                'namabank' => $this->input->post('namabank')
            );

        $this->load->model('model_bankdatel');
        $this->model_bankdatel->updatebank($arrdata, $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('berkas', "<script>alert('Nama Bank Berhasil Diubah');</script>");
        redirect('bankdatel');
    }
```

model (model/model_bankdatel.php)

```
public function updatebank($data, $id){
        $this->db->where('idbank', $id);
        $this->db->update('mt_bank', $data);
    }

    public function selectbank($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('idbank', $id);
        return $this->db->get('mt_bank')->row(); 
    }
```

Comment: Check if you are getting any value for $this->uri->segment(3)

Answer (score 0):

Your form URL is `site_url('bankdatel/updatebank/'.$row_bank['idbank'])`. It means 1 argument is passing to function. So get `$bankid` like this

```
public function updatebank($bankid){

    $arrdata = array(
            'namabank' => $this->input->post('namabank')
        );

    $this->load->model('model_bankdatel');
    $this->model_bankdatel->updatebank($arrdata, $bankid);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('berkas', "<script>alert('Nama Bank Berhasil Diubah');</script>");
    redirect('bankdatel');
}
```

And use `return` with update query in the model

```
return $this->db->update('mt_bank', $data);
```